# Object Orientation, Inheritance, Abstraction

Tags: java

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public static String city;

    Student() {
    }

    Student(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setCity(String c) {
        city = c;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
```

When considering the features of object orientation, which feature(s) is/are shown clearly in the program?

How can I know that above code is:

- Abstraction
- Encapsulation
- Data hiding
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism

Comment: Please ask the guy who wrote this code or let us know if you have any specific and detailed question.

Comment: Learn more about OOPS concept and then go through code again.

Comment: The best way to know whether the above code exhibits abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance or polymorphism is to find out what those four things actually are.  There are plenty of online resources that will help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abstraction - No (you don't have any abstract members or classes in your code).

Encapsulation - yes ( Binding code and data together - the class itself) .

polymorphism - no ( no multiple functions with same names ) .

inheritance - no (There is no class that inherits this one and vice versa )

Comment: thanks mohanen b, but i need to know how can catch whose methods just looking

Comment: @NuzLan I don't get you